# Django can't find static files after changing name of folder in project path

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project that I have been working on and I want to change the name of a folder in the project's file path. My current path to my project looks like this:

```
/Users/user/Documents/Python/Django Projects/ProjectName/
```

I want to change the project path to:

```
/Users/user/Documents/Python/Django_Projects/ProjectName/
```

When I do this change I get the following error message:

```
OSError at /
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'/Users/user/Documents/Python/Django Projects/ProjectName/assets'
```

In my `settings.py` file I have this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'), )
```

In the request META the PWD value is unchanged:

```
PWD '/Users/user/Documents/Python/Django Projects/ProjectName'
```

I'm fairly new to programming so I apologise for asking such a simple question, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clear you `.pyc` and try again?

Comment: Didn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: are you using pycharm or any other IDE? restart it as well

Comment: Yes I'm using pycharm, I've restarted pycharm but that had no effect and checked the project root in 'Project Structure', which has the correct path.